# Jquery multiple elements with single hasclass

Tags: javascript, jquery

**My js Code**

```
 if ($("#fb_connect_sell,#fb_connect").hasClass("connected")){
    }
```

how i can use multiple selector with single hasclass?

Comment: what do you want to check? whether one of the has the connected class or both has the class

Comment: both class is connected or not if not then addclass for both and  if yes then removeclass for both means toggle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to check whether one of the elements has the class then use .[is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
if ($("#fb_connect_sell,#fb_connect").is(".connected")){
}
```

if you want to check whether both has the class

```
if ($("#fb_connect_sell,#fb_connect").filter(".connected").length){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var $first = $("#fb_connect_sell");
var $second = $("#fb_connect");

if ($html.hasClass('connected') && $html.hasClass('connected')) {

  // do stuff 

}
```